# Scope of arrow function vs es5 function in setTimeout

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, this, settimeout, arrow-functions

I am experimenting with this and arrow functions.
Ran into some trouble regarding the lexical scope of arrow function in setTimeout.

The makeSound method returns this as the dog object. Why does it not take the scope of the global object since the arrow function is inside the setTimeout method? Interestingly, the whatIsThis method returns the Timeout object and not the global object. I am confused on this as well.

```js
const dog = {
  name: 'fluffy',
  type: 'dog',
  sound: 'woof!',
  makeSound: function() {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("makeSound", this)
    }, 1000)

  },
  whatIsThis: function() {
    setTimeout(function() {
      console.log("whatisthis", this)
    }, 1000)
  }
}


dog.makeSound() // returns dog obj
dog.whatIsThis() // returns Timeout obj


setTimeout(() => {
  console.log("global", this)
}, 1000) // returns global obj
```

Comment: [Answer to part 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361379/are-arrow-functions-and-functions-equivalent-exchangeable/34361380#34361380). [answer to part 2](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setTimeout#The_this_problem).

Comment: Are you sure dog.whatIsThis() logs the Timeout object. For me it logs the window object and it makes sense, since you declare a new lexical scope which is called by setTimeout. The arrow function takes its this from the outer lexical scope (makeSound in your case, which is equal to dog).

Answer (score 0):

> Why does it not take the scope of the global object since the arrow function is inside the setTimeout method?

The callback is not "inside" the `setTimeout` function. It is passed *as argument to* the `setTimeout` function.

Consider the following, equivalent code:

```
const dog = {
  name: 'fluffy',
  type: 'dog',
  sound: 'woof!',
  makeSound: function() {
    const cb = () => console.log("makeSound", this);
    setTimeout(cb, 1000)
  },
}
```

This code behaves exactly the same. The only difference is that the callback function is assigned to variable first before being passed to `setTimeout`.

This should demonstrate that the arrow function is not "inside" `setTimeout`, but rather inside `makeSound`. Arrow functions resolve `this` lexically, just like any other variable. So we have to find out what the value of `this` inside `makeSound` is. And in order to find that out, we have to look at how the method is called. Since it is called as `dog.makeSound()`, `this` refers to `dog`.

Answer (score -1):

The scope the arrow function gets declared in is the scope of the function *surrounding it* (`dog.makeSound`), not the function the arrow function gets passed to.

Whe  you call `dog.makeSound()`, `this` inside of the `makeSound` function refers to `dog`, thus it does so inside the arrow function too.

```
  // no matter what the surrounding is ...
  const that = this;
  /*no matter whats here*/(() => {
     console.log(that === this); // this will always be true
  })();
```

> Interestingly, the whatIsThis method returns the Timeout object and not the global object. I am confused on this as well.

Me too. That behaviour is strange, are you sure that you are not missinterpreting the consoles output?